# React-native 0.49.5 error 404

Tags: react-native, facebook-javascript-sdk

i am trying to install fbsdk in my react native project.I got a lot of errors at the beginning but now I just have this one which I think its more a react-native error than a fbsdk one.
This is it:

React packager ready.

Loading dependency graph, done.
Bundling `index.android.js`  [development, non-minified]  0.0% (0/1), failed.
error: bundling failed: NotFoundError: Cannot find entry file index.android.js in any of the roots: ["C:\Users\carlo\(project folder)"].

I still don't know why it is asking now for 'index.android.js' because on this version of react-native the correct file is index.js

this is my package.json file:
  "react": "16.0.0-beta.5",
    "react-native": "0.49.5",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "^0.6.3"

How can I fix this?
By the way, sorry for my english, ...

Comment: In your project directory, do `react-native -v` just to make sure you're on the right version.

Comment: I've checked it right now, and its the same version

Comment: Hi @Carlod did you find a solution to this? I'm also having issue upgrading to react 0.50

Comment: When you were upgrading, you might've ran into a merge conflict and picked to keep your version instead of the updated code. Make sure in your AppDelegate.m it is pointing to index:  `jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
`.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to eject your Create React Native App. See [Ejecting create react native app](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/blob/master/EJECTING.md)

However, if you do not want to eject (as there is no turning it back into create react native app), you can try the [Expo SDK for facebook](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/facebook.html)